# Django QuerySet returns duplicate instance using "filed__in" on list

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a model like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICE = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                        unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                          choices=STATUS_CHOICE,
                          default='draft')
    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

This model use tags provide by taggit.
So I want to find the similar blogs according to the number of the shared  tags the have(actually it is the example on 《django by example》).
I use this:

```
post_tag_ids = post.tags.values_list('id', flat=True)
similar_posts = Post.published.filter(tags__in=post_tag_ids) \
    .exclude(id=post.id)
similar_posts = similar_posts.annotate(same_tags=Count('tags')) \
                    .order_by('-same_tags', '-publish')[:4]
```

I know the what the first line means.But if the first line return the blog's id list `[1,2,3,4,5]` and the second line filter all posts.when a post have a id list like this `[1,2,6,7]` it will return `2` similar_blogs because they have 2 shared id.so I do not know what's going on?(I know annotate meas and I know aggregation means)But why this three lines of code can find the similar blogs according to the tags they shared! (Is there a mistake in Book?But I have tried it ,curious about why??)The third line just aggregate the count of **common tags** on every object but not the **shared** tags.How is this working?

I have tried this:

```
post_tag_ids = post.tags.values_list('id', flat=True)
```

output:`<QuerySet [1, 4, 5, 6, 7]>`

```
similar_posts = Post.published.filter(tags__in=post_tag_ids) \
    .exclude(id=post.id)
```

output:`<QuerySet [<Post: asdkjakls>, <Post: asdkjakls>, <Post: asdkjakls>, <Post: asdkjakls>, <Post: another post>]>`

but after:`similar_posts = similar_posts.annotate(same_tags=Count('tags'))`

it becomes **2**:`<QuerySet [<Post: asdkjakls>, <Post: another post>]>`,the same post `[<Post: asdkjakls>` merge into one

Answer (score 0):

try`similar_posts = Post.published.filter(tags__in=post_tag_ids) \
    .exclude(id=post.id).distinct()`to remove duplicate instance in queryset,see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) about distinct()